# Angular dynamic text based on condition

Tags: angular

I am new to angular , how do we change or make the text dynamic based on count for example if count > 2 set text as Teams if less than set sa Team.

what i tried

```
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs fxShow.gt-md [matTooltip]="item.teamCount"
                                        fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                       in {{item.teamCount}} {{item.Count > 1 ? 'Teams' : 'Team'}}
                                    </mat-cell>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `{{item.Count > 1 ? 'Teams' : 'Team'}}`? Isn't it working?

Comment: its not working , I am using latest angular

Comment: Your code seams to be functional, what's the issue ?

Comment: my bad supposed to be teamCount

Comment: Is your item.count really dynamic ? Can you show your component (typescript file) ?

Comment: yeah , still the same

Comment: I tried to use == it work but > does not work

Comment: Well for the moment just use == and switch 'Teams' and 'Team'. But can you provide a stackblitz or show code.

Answer (score 0):

Yo could use `*ngIF`

```
  in {{item.teamCount}} 
  <span *ngIf="item.Count > 1"> Teams</span>
  <span *ngIf="item.Count <= 1"> Team</span>




<mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs fxShow.gt-md [matTooltip]="item.teamCount" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  in {{item.teamCount}} 
  <span *ngIf="item.Count > 1"> Teams</span>
  <span *ngIf="item.Count <= 1"> Team</span>
</mat-cell>
```